# Logstash and Elasticsearch, possible data loss

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a log file with **18360** log-lines.I have a pattern to split and analyze the data, but unfortunately the amount of hits for the query *all* are only **8478** when I ran my logstash config. Then I deleted all the data in this index and got the hits down to zero. Then I once again ran my logstash config and then I got **11432** hits. This looks pretty random to me and even like there is a data loss. I pass my date through stdin and use following command to achieve this:

```
cat foo.log | /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f bar.conf
```

( I have also tested it with the direct file as input, the amount of hits is still random )

Is this an evidence for data loss or could this be something else ?

Comment: Perhaps the date filter doesn't match all the timestamps correctly and some `@timestamp` fields end up outside the time range you've selected in Kibana?

Comment: Well I checked it, the filter does match every timestamp correctly

Answer (score 1):

Do a `curl localhost:9200/logstash*/_count` to get a reliable count. If that's less than you are expecting you are indeed experiencing data loss.

If so, check your elasticsearch log for errors, check your logstash for errors as well. Common issues that could result in data loss: out of memory errors, problems with your mapping, network timeouts, problems with number of filehandles, etc. The logs will tell you.

If not, check the elasticsearch log for problems with queries kibana is sending. This can happen.

Comment: I really, really don't know why but when I do it with the **-vvv** param it works... `cat foo.log | /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f bar.conf -vvv`. Do you know why this works now ?